# Este título de la pregunta rompe la página de lista

Tags: bug

[Esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/55672/33102) se ve así en la lista de preguntas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando Firefox 52.

Comment: Lo encuentro normal en el listado de preguntas y no tiene ese comportamiento. _PD lo revisé desde una ventana incognito de Google Chrome_ :)

Comment: @Davlio He editado para mostrar que el problema está en Firefox.

Comment: quizas puedas reportar el error a Mozilla, igual es un bug de firefox. Saludos

Comment: Yo lo veo bien en Chrome/Windows 10. ¿Has intentado en modo de navegación segura, es decir, con todas las extensiones/complementos inhabilitados, con una caché vaciada y sin cookies previas?

Comment: Alguna vez lo vi así, por ejemplo en http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened (medallas entre el 11/5/16 y 16/5/16); pero no me puse a analizar el por qué

Comment: @Caleb recién probé en FireFox, y ese comportamiento no se ve más en https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=no+guardar+en+cascada+is%3Aq ¿Lo ves bien ahora?